# MayaBatch playblast fails to find activeEditor

Tags: python, maya

My goal is to do a playblast using MayaBatch. However I want to loop through multiple cameras and set that as the camera to playblast through. In order to do that I need to get the active panel but it fails every time.

How does one set the camera to playblast through if that doesnt work? Any help please?

```
# tried this...fails
panel = cmds.playblast(activeEditor=True).split('|')[-1]
cmds.setFocus(panel)
cmds.lookThru(camera)

# this also fails...
for mPanel in cmds.getPanel(type='modelPanel'):
    if cmds.modelEditor(mPanel, q=True, activeView=True):
        return mPanel
```

Comment: Last time I looked into playblasting without a UI session (eg mayabatch), it proved impossible. Perhaps something has changed, but afaik it can't be done.

Comment: You can use `cmds.ogsRender` for batch playblasts

Comment: I have been unable to make `ogsRender` render reliably in the past. But maybe @JokerMartini will have better luck :)

Comment: I've extensively looked into mayabatch playblasting and as you seem to already know, it's impossible. They do not support the setting of which camera to render through, or viewport settings regarding what is visible and what is not. So in short, it's not possible.